# How can I get the changed url of a known tab id queried before in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The situation is:

I queried the tab and know the active tab's id with:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {

    activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
    tabId = activeTab.id;
    ...
}
```

and injected some content script with:

```
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "content.js"});
```

which may change the url to a new location.

Something wired is that the return value of `activeTab.url` remains unchanged.

So is there any way to get the new url of a know tab id. Or I have to query the tabs again and find which tab matches the known id (the current active tab may not be the previous one), the get the new url?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The tabs array parameter is just a temporary copy created for your callback's sake, so `activeTab.url` is a copy of the tab's URL, it's not a self-refreshing pointer to the current tab.
2. Use [chrome.tabs.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-get):

   ```
   chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
       if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
           console.log('Tab %d was not found', tabId);
           return;
       }
       console.log('Async callback got tab %d URL: %s', tabId, tab.url);
   });
   ```

   You'll need `"tabs"` in [`"permissions"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).
   Or ["activeTab"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) if this is an active tab and your extension was invoked via user gesture.